# How to parse txt attachments (details.txt) with python email lib

Tags: python, email, attachment

I need to handle bounces, most of which will have a details.txt attached for further information. I check for multipart, content type and encoding, but I have issues: 
1) 
 details.txt might look like this: 
Action: failed 
Status: 4.3.0 
Remote-MTA: dns; abc.abc.com 
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 451 4.3.0 Your SMTP gateway is identified as not cool
    if you work in marketing, kill yourself, no joke, kill yourself

payload will return a list, and this is not what I want, 
 a) is there something speaking against working with 'part', without using payload? I need a dictionary with keys like 'action' and 'status' (str split(':')) but newlines like in diagnostic code are a problem so 
b) how do you parse a loose structure text, assuming the ':' appears more or less constantly REGEX ? 
 
2) another big issue: encoding, about 30 % of those details.txt are base64 encoded, payload always returns None when called with argument 'decode=True' in those cases, because they seem to be partly encoded it will look like:
not encoded :From blah blah blah
 and the encoded part:'base64string' 
 i could call b64decode with the pure string, but it has '\n' plus I need to 'detect' that string, not getting along with regex for me
 I woulder if you had/have the same issues, found nothing on the net, help much appreciated, thanks for your time

```
if msg.is_multipart():

   for part in msg.walk():

      if part.get_content_type() == 'message/delivery-status': 

          if part.get('Content-Transfer-Encoding') != 'base64':
                # get payload or work with part without payload

          else:
               # assuming base64 encoded...
```

Comment: What has IMAP to do with this? Looks like you got the message text already.

Answer (score 0):

That format is defined by [RFC 1894](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1894). Read the RFC, I think it answers most of your questions.